# MathJax overlaps the text

Tags: bug, status-review, mathjax, design

Here's what my All actions | Comments page looks like on Windows 10 with Firefox (default 100% magnification in Firefox and a custom scale factor in Windows settings):

[image: 1]

$\sum_{k \geq 0}$ in the first comment overlaps the text. The vertical spacing between the text and $\int_{-1}^1$ in the fourth comment is not ideal either.